# How to debug Ruby code under Docker with VSCode?

Tags: ruby, debugging, docker, visual-studio-code

To debug applications using [Byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) is handy, but this gem does not deliver the experience I could have using VSCode, for instance.

How to attach a debugger using Ruby 2.5.0, Docker and VSCode? I'm using the [Ruby extension for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rebornix.Ruby), that does support debugging, but I can't find any guide to use it with Docker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In github repo of this extension there is [an issue about that](https://github.com/rubyide/vscode-ruby/issues/220). I suggest you to check it out. Basically here is a suggestion from there:

> put it to Dockerfile in CMD:
>
> rdebug-ide --host 0.0.0.0 --port 1234 -- bin/rails s -b 0.0.0.0